# Problem with SaveChange() in Entity Framework Data model

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am facing a problem with the `SaveChanges()` method in Entity Framework. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it's not instead I get an error message saying:

> String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Can any one help me with this ....

thanks.

Comment: I think you need to give some more information. Does it always happen with the same types? What does the class/model look like? What does the corresponding table in the database look like? I'd say you're trying to insert a big value in a field that is too small to contain it completely, but more information would be nice.

Comment: In that case, you probably have an input (Textbox) that sometimes is shorter than the field length defined in the database, and sometimes it's too long. Check all your inputs - what database column do they map to? What maximum length is defined on that column??

Comment: .i used the same data in my form .... some times it's works and sometimes it's not

Answer (score -1):

By default all strings stored as NVARCHAR(4000). In case while string length above 4000 chars you get this error. To limit field length and add validation logics to your model use StringLength(...maxlen...) attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) with your model properties.

Comment: thanks Kuvalda.Spb.Ru for reply...i used the same data in my form .... some times it's works and sometimes it's not

Comment: Try to use EF Debug Visualizer - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/99468ece-689b-481c-868c-19e00e0a4e69/

Answer (score -1):

you can correct this problem on Data base Table on 
"nvarchar" and "varchar Columns " that you increase Lenght of Column on your Table 
also 
when you insert or Update with EF , you can check len of value and check your query With 
SQL Profiler when you call SaveChanges()method 
and you check your value in GET and SET methods on Domain Layer or Entities that EF get you

and below link is Useful :
[EF Exception: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380972/ef-exception-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-the-statement-has-been-t)
,
http://forums.asp.net/t/1660868.aspx/1