# EF Exception: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, exception

I have read many posts related to this issue, but couldn't find an answer.
I am trying to load a large amount of data from Excel into SQL Server.
Thousands of records. And I am getting this exception:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Obviously some values exceed the field size in the database.
The error comes from SQL Server AFIK.

---

**My question - How could I possibly know what record and what field value caused this?**

There are no specific details in EF exception, except the one I mentioned.

Any help is appreciated.

Some asked for the code fragment, but it's actually very simple, the problem is not with the code:

```
// employees is a List<Employee> collection loaded from Excel
using (var context = new Entities())
{
    employees.ForEach(e => context.Employee.AddObject(e));
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Also the suggested approach to use **DbEntityValidationException** (which is only available in Entity Framework 5.0) is not working, the **catch** block didn't catch the exception.

```
try
{
    ImportData();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var item in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**The only solution that I found** so far is to use SQL Server Profiler, and define the following events to monitor:

[image]

[image]

Now I can see the Email is too long.

Comment: Debug record by record until you find the offender, and check each field of the record against the db columns?

Comment: Please provide more information for example code sample, Data Structure and DataType of the fields you are trying to import.. this will make it easier in my opinion to lend some sort of direction

Comment: There is no way you can debug record by record using EF.
It is performed as one transaction.

Comment: I wanted to upvote your answer, but it's part of the question:)  Anyway, this technique worked perfectly for me.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: SQL Server Profiler works for me. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't find any answers that compared column widths directly from the database table to the widths of values we're trying to insert, so I went ahead and created methods in C# to do just that. Take a look below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342036/8644294

Answer (score 5):

You can't at that level.  SQL Server is rejecting the entire query.

I would add some pre-checks to the data against your database constraints for string size, date formats, etc.

Alternatively you could `TRIM` each string field in the raw data to the corresponding field size before trying to insert.

Comment: I can't perform any data cleanup or correction.
All I need is to find which value is causing the problem and expand corresponding field in the database.

Comment: Can you get the length of each string in the data to see which ones are longer that the destination field?

Answer (score 3):

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var item in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        //... inspect here 
    }
}
```

You can find the information you need inside foreach loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Just tried, but with catch is not intercepting the exception.

Comment: If this error is not raised in the DbEntityValidationException then it means that model is not in sync with the database. Try recreating the model from the database because it's still the easiest way to determine the problematic field.

Comment: Same here. On my SaveChanges in EF6.01 where one field is too long, I get a SqlException as the inner exception inside a UpdateException inside a DbUpdateException. My model is in sync.

Comment: Minus one - because the returned exception is not type of `DbEntityValidationException` so the answer is not helpful for this question.

Comment: not hte exception catched

Answer (score 1):

You can check data *before* saving, using EF metadata, and raise appropriate error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about truncation specifically, but here is a tip for when you get an exception that tells you to examine EntityValidationErrors. Usuaully when debugging it won't let you see that property (unless you already had an explicit catch). However, you can open up quick watch and type `$exception`. Now you should be able to drill in and find that property. You can also just type the following:

```
(System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string FindLongStrings(object testObject)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in testObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (ColumnAttribute attribute in propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true))
            {
                if (attribute.DbType.ToLower().Contains("varchar"))
                {
                    string dbType = attribute.DbType.ToLower();
                    int numberStartIndex = dbType.IndexOf("varchar(") + 8;
                    int numberEndIndex = dbType.IndexOf(")", numberStartIndex);
                    string lengthString = dbType.Substring(numberStartIndex, (numberEndIndex - numberStartIndex));
                    int maxLength = 0;
                    int.TryParse(lengthString, out maxLength);

                    string currentValue = (string)propInfo.GetValue(testObject, null);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue) && currentValue.Length > maxLength && lengthString!="max")
                        return testObject.GetType().Name + "." + propInfo.Name + " " + currentValue + " Max: " + maxLength;

                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }


foreach (object insert in dtx.GetChangeSet().Inserts)
            {
                string result = FindLongStrings(insert);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) == false)
                {
                    responseBuilder.Append(result);
                }
            }
```

If responseBuilder is not empty, then it contains the field name, allowed length and error message.

Comment: Your solution requires the field width information to be defined in the entity model (for eg: `[Column("SomefieldName", TypeName = "varchar(10)")]` annotation in `SomefieldName` property or in the `modelBuilder`), so sadly this didn't work out for me. So I went ahead and created methods to **get the column width information directly from the database table**. Checkout my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342036/8644294

Answer (score 0):

I have got that problem twice, and the problem is that when EF creates the table in the database, it sets `varchar(1)` to string attributes, so when i try to insert information it is not possible because of the length, I recommend you to check the fields in the table

Comment: This is far from any standard EF behavior so it has to do with circumstances you don't mention, making this not suitable for an answer. And "check the fields in the table" has been said before (and is too obvious to mention).